# ER diagram, relation owning side designation

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

Far as I understand, ER diagram is first of all a conceptual model, in a sense that it describes relations without regard to how they can be represented/implemented in actual database. But what if I want the diagram which both describes relationships and reflects which part of the relationship is an "owning" side? Say, in JPA some of relationships can be unidirectional; and if defined as bi-directional, one side of such a relationship is an owner and the other side is a reverse side - typically, for instance, the table having a foreign key to other table will be an owning side, and the referenced table will be a reverse side.

I wonder if there are any widely used ER notations which allow annotating an owning side (or a direction of unidirectional relation), or maybe at least showing which ways do which foreign keys point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common ER notations are variations of IE, Barker and IDEF1X. All of these use different symbols that should make it clear which side the foreign key would be (the "many" side).

Foreign keys are not pointers so they don't have direction. In object oriented programming, directionality refers to how pointers can be used to implement *control flow*. In other words directionality is a programming language feature rather than a data model feature. Modern DBMSs do not expose pointers in their data models. In fact ER modelling was developed in the 1970s as a way of abstracting the data model without the constraints of the pointer-based systems of that time.

UML notation does have the concept of directional associations because UML is used to model behavioural and programming constructs and not just data.

Comment: This answer is better than the one I was set to give.  I would add that foreign keys are part of the relational data model, but not part of the ER model.  This is actually a plus, in conceptual modeling.  The conceptual model can be developed before deciding on what kind of DBMS to use.

Comment: "All of these use different symbols that should make it clear which side the foreign key would be (the "many" side)." - just because A is related to B by many-to-one association, does not necessarily mean A holds a foreign key to B. The same effect can be achieved (I am not saying "should be") by using a join table connecting A and B. And in that case, I can even declare that B is an owning side in this relationship. Also, in 1-to-1, ER model will show same annotations for both ends, even though I will want one side to be owning one and another to be reverse one. The model will not reflect it.

Comment: Regarding foreign key direction, I probably now understand what you meant. While of course it says one property of a thing connects to another property of another thing, why would we assume the direction to  be outbound from referring entity, not inbound to one? OK, I suppose you are right. But my question was not about "foreign key direction", it's more about "owning side" as a notion. Did you never have to work with JPA or Hibernate based applications? If you did, you probably understand what I meant. What sort of diagram would you propose me to use to represent that along with ER model?

Comment: I think I will ultimately discard the idea of showing JPA's owning side. Instead, I'll stick to ER diagrams but keep them close to physical represenation - like, expand many-to-many relations to two one-to-many + join-table entity, and so on. That way, it will probably actually be clear which side holds foreign keys, and that may just be enough.